# WinForm Controls for .NET Compact Framework

Tags: winforms, windows-mobile, compact-framework, user-controls

I'm looking to invest in a UI control toolkit for a Compact Framework 3.5 project for Windows Mobile 5 and later. All I can find is the Resco MobileForms Toolkit (http://www.resco.net/developer/mobileformstoolkit/overview.aspx). I have two questions...

Are there any other good WinForm control collections out there?

Any experience with the Resco controls? How have they been?

Answer (score 1):

What about the [Smart Device Framework](http://www.smartdeviceframework.com/)? The GUI components don't look as fancy as those in the Resco toolkit, but SDF seems to have a broader basic selection ([SDF doc](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/)). I've never used either (have only used MFC on WinCE), but would also like to hear about CF development experiences.

Comment: I'd love to see some screen shots of SDF controls on screen. Anyone know of any?

Answer (score 1):

MiraByte has [these controls](http://www.mirabyte.com/de/produkte/windows-mobile.html).

Answer (score 0):

+1 on the Resco Toolkit. I've used it for quite some time now and I must say that if you need slick UI, they're the way to go. Apart from what Ivan's already said, the WYSIWYG template designers for thing like AdvancedList or DetailView let you do rather impressive things pretty easily.